# Issues setting up IHttpClientFactory in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to set up an instance on `IHttpClientFactory` within `.NET Core 3.1`.

I have a route which is intended to make an GET request to an endpoint supplied by the user and return the result as a `byte[]`.

In the first sample shown below I am getting an error in Visual Studio stating, "IHttpClientFactory is a type which is not valid in the current context".

But this is the type I am specifying in my constructor for `DemoProcessor()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0119?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0119)

What am I doing wrong below and how should I be calling, or what argument should I be passing to `DemoProcessor()` in order for this to run correctly?

```
namespace POC_APP.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/")]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Interact", Name ="Interact")] 
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetStringFromEndpointAsync(string url)
        {
            var proc = new DemoProcessor(IHttpClientFactory); // HERE
            var res = await proc.MakeGetRequest(url);
            return res.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

As seen above I am trying to call my `DemoProcessor()` class which contains the implementation of `IHttpClientFactory` as below.

```
namespace POC_APP
{
    public class DemoProcessor 
    {

        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public DemoProcessor(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) =>
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

        public async Task<byte[]> MakeGetRequest(string url)
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("foo", "bar");

                    var documentResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url.Replace(".exe", ""));

                    response = Convert.FromBase64String(documentResponse);
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding the HTTP client like so in `Startup.cs` which is called by `Program.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DemoProcessor` has been setup to expect an instance of something which implements `IHttpClientFactory`, what is being passed is just the name 'IHttpClientFactory'. This wouldn't compile in any scenario. If you wanted to give the type even then you would need to do something like typeof(IHttpClientFactory).

As dependency injection comes out-of-the-box, you just need to inject `IHttpClientFactory` into your `DemoController`, and then pass it on.

```
namespace POC_APP.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/")]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public DemoController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        [HttpGet("Interact", Name ="Interact")] 
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetStringFromEndpointAsync(string url)
        {
            var proc = new DemoProcessor(_httpClientFactory);
            var res = await proc.MakeGetRequest(url);
            return res.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, better still, you could register your `DemoProcessor` in the DI service and inject that into the controller, which will automatically get the `IHttpClientFactory` injected into it.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, the DI service? I'm a little new to this

Comment: @3therk1ll, have a read of [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) on this. It should clarify things